# Isolate the state abbreviation of and address

Tags: joomla, state, string-parsing, abbreviation

Is there a way to pull out the state abbreviation from an address?  I am using an event calendar extension for Joomla for my site and it currently only stores the city and county separately in the database but it does give the address all together, ie. 123 Main St., Townsville, ID 55555.  Is there a way to grab the two letters of the state and spit that out instead?  Even if there might be a way to grab all of the two letter occurrences and then compare those to a list of state abbreviations to validate.

Thanks
Jason

Answer (score 0):

The problem with extracting the information the way you're asking to is that some people might enter the entire State name, some might abbreviate the state, some might misspell the state... etc.

You can't count on people to give you the right data... it's just a fact of programming.

You could extend the database and form to include the State separately... going further, you could use a predetermined Ajax AutoComplete extension or a Dropdown List in order to ensure the user is selecting the correct State.

In my apps, I enter all of the US States and all of the Canadian Provinces in a `Region` table. Then in the `Person` table, I have an `int State`. That way I can join the person's state to the region table and save valuable db space.  But that's just me.

```
dbo.Person
|  ID  |  Name  |  Address  |  Zip  |  StateID  |  etc...  |


dbo.Region
|  ID  |  ParentID  |  Name  |
```